# I run the script/tool(import-hive.sh) and i can search the hive entities like tables, database, views, columns,but no lineage, is that nomal?

Tags: apache-atlas, data-lineage

before install atlas, there are two hive table named atlas_testm and atlas_testm_ext(is a view based on atlas_testm) in my hive database cluster.

after install atlas and run the atlas services , i run the script named import-hive.sh,i can saw these two hive table in atlas ui web by search,but no lineage which is relationship of atlas_testm and atlas_testm_ext,is that nomal?

i want to know whether the script named import-hive.sh does not support hive table's history lineage import?

this problem has been bothering me for a long time.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKuSt.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdc0l.png)

Answer (score 0):

Atlas helps you keep track of the lineage.

If you first have a cluster without atlas, the lineage is simply not tracked, so installing it later will not make it historically available.

However, after you install Atlas, the relationship between new tables that are created based on other tables should become clear.

---

In short: If you care about lineage, it is best to install Atlas before bringing your cluster to production.